# Getting version number for package in Github Actions

Tags: .net, github, nuget, github-actions, github-package-registry

I'm trying to set up my "first" GitHub action to publish the NuGet package of .NET library to my private GitHub Packages registry.

I want my action to get the version number of the package from the `.csproj` file. I'm trying to follow the instructions here but looks like they hard-code the version number:
https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-nuget-registry
[image]

How do I get the version number from the `.csproj` file?

Here's my `release.yml` file so far:

```
name: Publish MyApp NuGet to GitHub Packages

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      with:
        dotnet-version: 6.0.x
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --no-restore
      
  package:
  
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Create NuGet package
      run: dotnet pack --configuration Release
  
  publish:
  
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Publish to GitHub Packages
      run: dotnet nuget push "bin/Release/MyApp.1.0.0.nupkg" --source "github"
```

And here's the `nuget.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <clear />
        <add key="github" value="https://nuget.pkg.github.com/MY_GITHUB_COMPANY_ACCOUNT/index.json" />
    </packageSources>
    <packageSourceCredentials>
        <github>
            <add key="Username" value="MY_GITHUB_USERNAME" />
            <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="MY_GITHUB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN" />
        </github>
    </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

And here's the section in `.csproj` file where I define package related info:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <Authors>MyCompany, LLC</Authors>
    <Company>MyCompany, LLC</Company>
    <Description>MyApp Library</Description>
    <Version>1.2.1</Version>
    <RepositoryUrl>https://github.com/MY_GITHUB_COMPANY_ACCOUNT/my-app</RepositoryUrl>
    <Copyright>MyCompany, LLC (c) 2015 - 2023</Copyright>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [Get CSProj Version](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/get-csproj-version) GH Action. This action should retrieve the current version from a .NET `.csproj` project file and provide the output that can be used in the next steps.

**Example:**

```
...

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Get version
        id: package_version
        uses: KageKirin/get-csproj-version@v1.0.0
        with:
          file: src/project.csproj # Specify your .csproj file path

      - name: Publish to GitHub Packages
        run: dotnet nuget push "bin/Release/MyApp.${{ steps.test.package_version.version }}.nupkg" --source "github"
```

**Similar action**: [get-net-sdk-project-versions-action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/get-net-sdk-project-versions-action)

Comment: I'm new to GitHub actions so I never knew this existed. This is cool and works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to have version numbers, so you don't have to think about setting up this manually. You can use [GitVersion](https://gitversion.net/docs/).

```
- name: Install GitVersion
  uses: gittools/actions/gitversion/setup@v0.9.7
  with:
    versionSpec: '5.x'

- name: Determine Version
  uses: gittools/actions/gitversion/execute@v0.9.7
  with:
    useConfigFile: true
```

This will set env var `$GITVERSION_SEMVER` and then in your push step you will just say:

```
- name: Your project
  run: |
    dotnet pack -p:Version=$GITVERSION_SEMVER projectToPack.csproj
    dotnet push ...
```

And one more thing. If you specify version in `.csproj` manually `pack/push` will take into consideration that number, so there is no need for -`p:Version` thingy.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could be using [this action](https://github.com/euberdeveloper/ga-project-version)

It is not for C# but you can handle it by specifying a specific path and a specific version prop